# Emacs directory tree for git / vc

Tags: git, emacs, version-control

I'm looking for a emacs plugin like dirtree or speedbar that opens the root
directory of my git project.

Currently I'm using sr-speedbar and what happens is that whenever I move to a
different file, the root directory of my speedbar changes to the directory of
that particular file. Instead what I would like is that the root directory
stays the same and expands the directories towards my current file.

So for example if I have a Project with a .git, src and lib directory it
would look like this:

[image]

When I go to lib/foo the tree automatically changes to this:

[image]

Instead I want it to expand the directory like this:

[image]

I couldn't find a tree plugin that does this (or if speedbar does it) so
hopefully someone could help me out with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the goal to quickly and recursively find files from a git directory base, I like projectile: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Projectile. I know it isn't a bar, but it shares some goals.

Comment: I use Helm-ls-git for that https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-ls-git. But thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[project-explorer](https://github.com/sabof/project-explorer) seems to do that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LaszloPapp You have no idea what this link leads to, do you? There's no "essential parts", it's an Emacs package which the question author will need to install to judge if it's suitable for them. The link leads to the homepage. There's no way I'm going to duplicate the whole README inside the answer.